# How to skip an implementation with specs2

Tags: scala, specs2

In specs2, given a list of implementations that should satisfy a given test suite. How can I skip implementations that are not available in the current environment, but still display a message informing the user that the tests were skipped for that given implementation?

I tried this, but the message is not displayed when the implementation is not available

```
case class ImplToTest(name: String, impl: Option[Impl])

val toTest: List[ImplToTest] = ...
val testSuite: Impl => Fragment = ...

toTest.foreach { underTest =>
  s"${underTest.name}" >> underTest.map(testSuite).getOrElse(org.specs2.specification.create.DefaultFragmentFactory.text("This implementation is being skipped"))
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would something like that work for you?

```
class TestSpec extends org.specs2.mutable.Specification {

  val implementations = List("now", "never", "always")

  implementations.foreach { implementation =>
    if (implementation == "never")
      s"$implementation" >> skipped("NOT NOW")
    else
      s"$implementation" >> {
        "do this" >> ok
        "do that" >> ok
      }
    br

  }
}
```

Comment: Yes it works, thank you. Although the implementation is less pretty and more side-effecty. This is the change I made: https://github.com/jedesah/Quasar/commit/1713d07749d38024553c7e7cdd58adc027545f2b. Is there a way of accomplishing the same thing without making the return type of the function `Unit`?

Comment: If you replace `fss.toList.foreach` by `Fragments.foreach(fss)`, don't you get back `Fragments` instead of `Unit`?

Comment: If I do that, the types don't seem to line up. Perhaps my unfamiliarity with the Fragments API is at fault. I do know that just making the above switch triggers a compile error, expected `Fragments`, but found `org.specs2.execute.Skipped` on line 69

Comment: That's right, I think you need to wrap the first part of the `if/else`: `Fragments(s"$implementation" >> skipped("NOT NOW"))`